# How to browse pdf file from application

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, upload

I am developing an application which needs to upload a pdf file.
The pdf may be downloaded from any website or may be downloaded from gmail.

How can I browse the downloaded pdf from my application?
If not possible, how can I implement the same.

Comment: Might be `UIDocumentInteractionController` used for this case

Comment: @JonSnow: I think, ' UIDocumentInteractionController ' is viewing the documents. I need to browse the downloaded document from an iOS application.